# Set IP address from a list in VBS

Tags: networking, file-io, vbscript, setup-deployment, static-ip-address

Ok so i'm in the process of imaging a bunch of PC's with Fog. My boss is a stickler for setting everything manually, he won't even let me use Print servers to manage the printers...

Anyway, to make a long story short I've made great strides by writing a bunch of printer install scripts and a couple other small monitoring and other scripts.

So it's now come down to setting IP addresses,  which as usual must be set static without the normal AD\DHCP ezmode.

So i was hoping to get some help with this new script i Frankensteined together.

This script "Should"

1. Read the hostname it's run on (Working!)
2. Open Computerlist.csv on a network share (Mostly working)
3. Parse ComputerList.csv, looking for hostname (Works usually, but is case sensative)
4. take the information listed for hostname, and set variables (Looses .'s when pulled)
5. Use those variables to configure the network connection. (problematic because of the above #4)

I'm actually pretty surprised i wasn't able to google search a script that had already been built to do this.

**Here is what i've cobbled together so far, it seems to be pretty close but I'm missing something wrong and i just can't sort it out.**

```
option explicit

Dim WshShell
Dim ObjShell
Dim objSysInfo
Dim strComputerName
Dim strFile

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
" RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
Else
end if 

'* Pulls Computer name and sets it to variable
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject( "WinNTSystemInfo" )
strComputerName = objSysInfo.ComputerName

'* Loop through CSV file, read entries, store them in an array
dim CONNECTION : set CONNECTION = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
dim RECORDSET : set RECORDSET = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

CONNECTION.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\carmichaels\e\PCSetup\IPchanger\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

RECORDSET.Open "SELECT * FROM ComputerList.csv WHERE ComputerName = '" & strComputerName & "'", CONNECTION, 3, 3

' //// For testing \\\\
WScript.Echo RECORDSET.Source
' \\\\ For testing ////

if RECORDSET.EOF then
    WScript.Echo "Record not found"
    WScript.Quit
else
    dim strIPAddress : strIPAddress = RECORDSET("IPAddress") & ""
    dim strSubnetMask : strSubnetMask = RECORDSET("SubnetMask") & ""
    dim strGateway : strGateway = RECORDSET("Gateway") & ""
    dim intGatewayMetric : intGatewayMetric = 1
    dim strDns1 : strDns1 = RECORDSET("Dns1") & ""
    dim strDns2 : strDns2 = RECORDSET("Dns2") & ""
    dim strDns3 : strDns3 = RECORDSET("Dns3") & ""
    WScript.Echo strIPAddress
end if

'* Set IP address information stored in variables
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set address name=""Local Area Connection"" static " & strIPAddress & " " & strSubnetMask & " " & strGateway & " " & intGatewayMetric, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set dns name=""Local Area Connection"" static "& strDns1, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip add dns name=""Local Area Connection"" addr="& strDns2, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip add dns name=""Local Area Connection"" addr="& strDns3, 0, True
Set objShell = Nothing
```

My problem is when i run this script, It claims line 28 chr 1 cannot open the file (on 32 bit machines).

And on a 64 Bit machine, **(i run it with the following in a .bat [%windir%\SysWoW64\cscript \server\share\folder\folder\IPchanger.vbs] )**  it runs through but the IP address is missing dots.  ex. 10.1.0.57 appears as 10.1057 in my test window, and will fail to run again claiming the file is open or locked.

Here's the CSV file

```
ComputerName,IPAddress,SubnetMask,Gateway,Dns1,Dns2,Dns3
CLONE2,10.1.0.57,255.255.255.0,10.1.0.1,10.1.0.18,10.1.0.13,10.1.0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about your file open errors, for me line 28 is

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

But to avoid the problem with the dots, using Jet OLEDB text filter, you need to define a Schema.ini file for the csv. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I think Jet asumes your IPs to be decimal numbers, not text.